Simplifying two rational expressions with roots
Can you please check the steps I followed to simplify the following two expressions?
Given that $0 < n < 1$, simplify:
$$\left( \frac{\sqrt{1+n}}{\sqrt{1+n} - \sqrt{1-n}} + \frac{1-n}{\sqrt{1-n^2} + n-1} \right) \times \left( \sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2} - 1} - \frac{1}{n} \right)$$
After rationalizing and finding a common denominator:
$$\left( \frac{1+n+\sqrt{1-n^2}}{1+n-(1-n)} + \frac{(1-n) \cdot \sqrt{1-n^2} - (1-n) (n-1)}{1-n^2-(n-1)^2} \right) \times \left( \sqrt{\frac{1-n^2}{n^2}} - \frac{1}{n} \right)$$
After solving the square of the binomial and adding/subtracting:
$$\left( \frac{1+n+\sqrt{1-n^2}}{2n} + \frac{(1-n) \cdot \sqrt{1-n^2} - (1-n) (n-1)}{-2n^2+2n} \right) \times \left( \sqrt{\frac{1-n^2}{n^2}} - \frac{1}{n} \right)$$
After factoring out and finding a common denominator:
$$\left( \frac{1+n+\sqrt{1-n^2}}{2n} + \frac{-(n-1) \cdot (\sqrt{1-n^2} - n + 1))}{-2n(n-1)} \right) \times \left( \frac{\sqrt{1-n^2}-1}{n} \right)$$
After finding a common denominator:
$$\frac{1+n+\sqrt{1-n^2}+\sqrt{1-n^2} - n + 1}{2n} \times \frac{\sqrt{1-n^2}-1}{n}$$
After adding/subtracting:
$$\frac{2+2\sqrt{1-n^2}}{2n} \times \frac{\sqrt{1-n^2}-1}{n}$$
After factoring out:
$$\frac{\sqrt{1-n^2}+1}{n} \times \frac{\sqrt{1-n^2}-1}{n}$$
After multiplying: $\frac{1-n^2-1}{n^2} = -1$

The second expression:
$$ \left( \frac{\left( a + \sqrt[3]{a^2x} \right) \div \left( x + \sqrt[3]{ax^2} \right) - 1}{\sqrt[3]{a} - \sqrt[3]{x}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}} \right)^6$$
After solving the double fraction:
$$ \left( \frac{a + \sqrt[3]{a^2x} - x - \sqrt[3]{ax^2}}{\left( \sqrt[3]{a} - \sqrt[3]{x} \right) \times \left( x + \sqrt[3]{ax^2}\right)} - \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}} \right)^6$$
Finding a common denominator:
$$ \left( \frac{a\sqrt[3]{x} - x\sqrt[3]{a}}{x\sqrt[3]{a^2} - x\sqrt[3]{x^2}} \right)^6$$
After rationalization:
$$\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{ax}}{x}\right)^6$$
After exponentiation: $\frac{a^2x^2}{x^6} = \frac{a^2}{x^4}$
Can you check if these two solutions are correct? Thanks in advance!

@ClaudeLeibovici That is not given, unfortunately. The result does not have to be a constant, as in the first example.
